# Rails 5: unable to use env.find_asset in tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I've followed along with the tutorial found [here](http://matteodepalo.github.io/blog/2013/01/31/how-to-create-custom-stylesheets-dynamically-with-rails-and-sass/) but am unable to get any tests related to the new code to work. Specifically, this is where Rails complains:

```
env = if Rails.application.assets.is_a?(Sprockets::Index)
  Rails.application.assets.instance_variable_get('@environment')
else
  Rails.application.assets
end

asset = env.find_asset(tmp_asset_name)
```

The exact error I get is:

```
undefined method `find_asset' for nil:NilClass
```

What's the reason behind `env being nil in test environments? (note: I am using minitest_rails)

Comment: is `Rails.application.assets` nil?

Comment: Nope. The code in the first bit of the if statement fires, so it `is_a` (Sprockets::Index). Rails.application.assets is not nil, however using the method instance_variable_get with @environment returns nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `assets.compile = false` sprockets is disabled

In test environment you can use:

```
Rails.application.assets_manifest.find('cable.js').first
=> #<Sprockets::Asset:3ff35fce4248 "file:///" ... >
```

In place of:

```
# asset = env.find_asset(tmp_asset_name)
asset = Rails.application.assets_manifest.find(tmp_asset_name).first
```

Comment: Could you explain how that line of code would be used in my example?

Comment: Thank you that works great. How would one run a conditional to check if the test env is being used? In order to use `find_asset` in dev, and `find(file).first` in test

Comment: @mycellius `Rails.env.test?`